# Can't launch a cordova ios app on device or simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cordova

Using Xcode 5.1.1

I have a cordova-based iOS app, which used to work just fine both in simulator and on an attached device. I would press the "run" button, and it would launch on a selected target. All was good.

However, after seemingly not really changing anything, I can't get the application to launch, at all. It builds just fine, other than a few warnings (which were also present before), there are no issues that I can see. After building, nothing happens. I see a "build succeeded" message, and nothing else. The app doesn't launch on a device, nor does it launch on a simulator.

I'm pretty much at loss as to what to do. I've read through every stackoverflow post that's even remotely related, I've reset the simulator, cleaned the project, deleted temp build files, etc etc, but nothing seems to work. I've reinstalled Xcode, but that didn't help.

I can create a new project from Xcode, and that launches just fine. So it's something in my project, but I'm not sure what to look for.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are there any logs in the console?

Comment: @GenieWanted Not that I can see. Console seems to be blank.